# Absolute value of derivative of complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be complex function analytic at point $z_0$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0$
Prove: $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{|f(z) - f(z_0)|}{|z - z_0|}$ = $|f'(z_0)|$

*Solution*:
$f(z)$ analytic at $z_0$ therefore exists neighbourhood around $z_0$ s.t. $f(z)$ is differentiable at every point of it.
Then $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$ which means existence of $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}$ = $f'(z_0)$
Since $|z|$ is continous in $\mathbb{C}$:
$$|f'(z_0)|  =  \left|\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}\right|  =  \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{|f(z) - f(z_0)|}{|z - z_0|}$$

Remarks:
1. I didn't use the fact that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$
2. The solution seems too simple (suspicious that I didn't use C.R. equations here)

Could you please tell whether am I on the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is correct, and indeed the fact that $f'(z_0)\ne 0$ is not needed for the conclusion. But you should check whether you correctly understood what needs to be done. The title of your question has "derivative of absolute value", which is not the same thing as "absolute value of derivative".

Comment: Yes, the problem required also to prove that
$lim_{z \to z_0}arg(f(z) - f(z_0)) - arg(z - z_0) = arg(f'(z_0))$
and for this equation, that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ requirement is clear.

Fixed the title, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be further streamlined. We don't actually need to know that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood. Being told that $f'(z_0) \ne 0$, we already know  that $f'(z_0)$ **exists**; this is implicitly a part of assumption $f'(z_0) \ne 0$. Thus,
 $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}$  exists, and is equal to $f'(z_0)$. The rest goes as in your post.